# One Word To Describe People Lying to Gain Something for Themselves to a Third Party

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the word that describes the actions of a person who fabricates horrendous lies to another person/person's, in the hope they will reject the person they want to have in their own circle, by the person telling the lies, so the lier will gain this person back for themselves because they have influenced the other person/persons to believe the stories.

Comment: This question is difficult to read as it is one long run-on sentence but would be improved by splitting separate clauses into separate sentences, possibly using example names such as "Alice" and "Bob" for each person, making it easier for the reader to understand who does what. *(Yes, I was being sarcastic by making that a run-on sentence myself.)*

Comment: I think you're requested to write a sentence with a blank in it when asking for word requests.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments.  It is my first time to this site and I will have to read the help center before posting again.  The word I'm looking for applied to the work within private intelligence...Lois

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are referring to a  ***[manipulator](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/manipulator)***:

> - a person who controls people to their own advantage, often unfairly or dishonestly:
>
>   - *She was, said the judge, a ruthless and scheming manipulator*.

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest *two-faced.*

**Two-faced:** "Not honest or sincere: saying different things to different people in order to get their approval instead of speaking and behaving properly". (Merriam-Webster)